# How to transfer vm from Virt manager to ovirt

Tags: virtual-machine, centos7

Hello someone please help me solve this problem. I have four VM:

1. VM database 1,
2. VM database 2,
3. VM database 3,
4. VM for APPS(TNMS)

All this VM I create in virt-manager, I am using CentOs7. And I have 3 server, this server, setup using Ovirt.

1. node a
2. node b
3. node c

My question is how to transfer all file VM in the virt-manager to Ovirt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [little Perl script for importing virtual machines into oVirt](http://git.annexia.org/?p=import-to-ovirt.git;a=tree) that may be useful.  Documentation is in the script.